# FBConnect app invite in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi, I am trying to implement app request to my facebook friends. I tried the following code to sent the app invite:

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSDictionary *testingDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"5", @"wow",
                             @"1", @"testing",
                             nil];

NSString *testStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:testingDic];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Learn how to make your iOS apps invite.",  @"message",
                               @"Check this out", @"notification_text",
                               testStr, @"data",
                               nil];

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"apprequests"
                  andParams:params
                andDelegate:self];
```

I can see the above code executes with out error, but I am not getting the Request Id from the Facebook as response and more over I can't see my App request in Facebook.

Please help me out.

Comment: i tried the above code in stimulator is it an issue?

Comment: I had fixed the issue . The problem was not with the code , it was with the environment. I was trying in sandbox environment , when i tried with production APP id i was able to send an fb invite :-)